# Trying to multiply all elements in a list of sublists with elements in another list in lisp

Tags: list, common-lisp

I'm trying to multiply a list with n sublists with a list with n scalars. It's supposed to work like this:

```
(kmult-matrix '((3 4 2 4) (2 5 6 9) (1 -2 8 10))   '(2 3 5)) 
=> ((6 8 4 8) (6 15 18 27) (5 -10 40 50))
```

Each nth sublist is multiplied with the nth scalar in the second list. Here's what I got this far:

```
(defun kmult-matrix (m k)
  (apply 'append (mapcar (lambda (x1)
            (mapcar (lambda (x2)
                            (mapcar (lambda (x3)
                                    (* x3 x1))
                                    x2))
                          m))
          k)))
```

Which results in:

```
((6 8 4 8) (4 10 12 18) (2 -4 16 20) (9 12 6 12) (6 15 18 27) (3 -6 24 30) (15 20 10 20) (10 25 30 45) (5 -10 40 50))
```

Hope it's ok to ask this as it is for an assigment and I have the feeling that I'm not far away from the solution. Btw, I have to use mapcar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a lot easier than that. Remember that `mapcar` can take more than one list. Thus:

```
(defun kmult-matrix (m k)
  (mapcar (lambda (list k)
            ;; inside here you get a list and 
            ;; it's corresponding multiplier k
            ...)
          m
          k))
```

The result from the outer map would be a list with as many elements as there are sublists `m` (and corresponding elements in `k`). Inside the lambda you do another map over `lst` that does the multiplication per element. so that inner map produces once list answer per element in the outer map.